# Tooltip from selection pseudo selectors

Tags: javascript, html, css

in Medium.com website i want to know how tooltip evolves when double clicking a word or sentence to display tooltip with share, edit and other things.

[image: tooltip]

Answer (score 1):

The code is minified but I guess the way it is done is as follows:
A hidden element is added to the page. Using chrome dev tools I managed to see its class is 'buttonset--highlightmenu'.

An event listener for dblclick is added to the page. The event handler takes note of the click's position. Then after a timeout it gets the selected range (using window.getSelection). The next stem is to hold the text (so it can be used for the actions) and making the hidden element visible at the correct position.

If you want to try rev-engineer their code, look in dev tools, sources tab. They have 3 js files, 2 of which contain reference to this element.

Just in case you feel lazy, you can use a [selection sharer library](https://github.com/xdamman/selection-sharer).

Comment: Thanks for your answer and generic word "selection sharer library". :)